# Need help in understanding how to Calculate Estimation and Variance

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, variance

I have this problem at hand and have no idea on how to approach it. Any leads/solution would be appreciated.

You roll a fair $6$-sided die, and flip a coin n times where n is the number on the die. If $H$ refers to the number of heads observed after **n** coin flips, find

1. $E[H|n]$ and $\operatorname{Var}(H|n)$ for $n$ in set ${1,2,3,4,5,6}$
2. Find $E[H]$ and $\operatorname{Var}(H|n)$

Comment: If you flip a fair coin 6 times, what is the expected number of heads?

Comment: 3 heads. Whats the relevance though?

Comment: Your answer is that $E[H|6]=3$. Now try $d=1,2,3,4,5$

Comment: I see. So E[H|1] = 0.5; E[H|2]=1 and so on till 6 are the different estimates. But variance is defined as E[X-E[X]]^2 right? While E[X] can be substituted with E[H|t] where t belongs to {1,2,3,4,5,6}, what do I substitute X with? H|2 has no meaning right?

Comment: Each flip is an independent Bernoulli trial, so the variance of $n$ flips is $n$ times the variance of one flip. I recommend looking up the Binomial distribution on Wikipedia.

Comment: Okay so I performed the calculations again after reading the Wiki page. Based on the value of H the value of P changes, but if E[H|6] = np = 6*0.5 = 3, then Variance is just 6*0.5*(1-0.5)? @Joe

Comment: Yes, $\operatorname{Var}(H|d=6)=6(0.5)(1-0.5)$

Comment: Great, thanks. When I tried to find E[H] using the law of total expectation I got Ed{E[H|d]} = SUM(E[H|d]*P(d)) which is 0.5*1/6 + 1*1/6 and so on. Is that correct?

Additionally for the Variance of H, how do we solve that part?

Comment: Looks correct to me. For variance, look up the law of total variance.

Comment: I did but I am unable to calculate Var(E[H|d]), the other part is just SUM(Pi*variance i) but this I dont know how to calculate. Any suggestions? If I define Var(x) as E[X^2] - (E[X])^2, i'm not sure on how I should find E[(H|d)^2]

Comment: You already calculated $\operatorname{Var}(H|d)$ for each value of $d$, so what part of $\sum_d \left(p_d \operatorname{Var}(H|d) \right)$ don't you know how to calculate?  For the other part, since $ \operatorname{E}(H|d) = d/2$, we have $\operatorname{Var}( \operatorname{E}(H|d) ) = \operatorname{Var}( d/2 ) = \operatorname{Var}( d )/4$

Comment: Yeah I was asking about the second part and I did reach the point of Var(d/2). When we do Var(d)/4 for all the values of d - 1 through 6, isnt the variance of a constant 0? Does that mean this part of the answer is 0?

Comment: No, perhaps the correct notation is $\operatorname{E}(H|D) =D/2$. Either way, this is a random quantity that has a positive variance. What is $\operatorname{Var}(D)$ as defined in your post?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think Var[E(H|d)] = 1/6*(0.5sq+1sq+1.5sq+2sq+2.5sq+3sq) - (10.5/6)^2 which gives 35/48

Comment: That's what I get also

Answer (score 0):

Once $D=d$ is fixed, you just need to focus on the outcome of the coin flips (which is random).

Let's do one example for $d=3$ and you can fill in the rest. Let $H_d = H|d$ be the random variable that denotes the number of heads in $d$ coin tosses. You have:

$P(H_d=0) = (1/2)^3$ (TTT)

$P(H_d=1) = {3 \choose 1} (1/2)^3$ (HTT, THT, TTH)

$P(H_d=2) = {3 \choose 2} (1/2)^3$ (HHT, THH, HTH)

$P(H_d=3) = (1/2)^3$ (HHH)

Now you can compute the expected value as $(1/2)^3 \left( 0 \times 1 + 1 \times {3 \choose 1} + 2 \times {3 \choose 2} + 3 \times 1\right) = 1.5$.

Similarly you can compute the second moment and variance.

To put it together, you can compute:

$E[H] = \sum_{d=1}^6 E[H|D=d]P(D=d)$, i.e. the law of total expectation.

Comment: Yes, I got that part. Having difficulty calculating Var(E[H|d]) though. What do I do when it reduces to Var(d)/4 for d in range 1 through 6? Is the answer to this part just 0?

Comment: First calculate $E[H_d]$ and $E[(H_d)^2]$ based on the method I outlined above. Then compute $Var(H_d) =  E[(H|d)^2] - E[H_d]^2$.